# Does file(GENERATE) resolve variables?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to generate a file, but it fails to resolve variables. Since file(generate) runs during the generate step, are there limitations to what variables it can resolve? (e.g. only cache variables?)

My variables don't get resolved despite them being defined.

```
message("Registered composites: ${COURAGE_COMPOSITES}")
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml INPUT ${INPUT_PATH}/output.xml.in)
```

output.xml.in

```
   <imports>
      $<$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:"${COURAGE_COMPOSITES}","">>:<import iuts="yes"$<ANGLE-R>$<JOIN:${COURAGE_COMPOSITES},</import$<ANGLE-R><import iuts="yes"$<ANGLE-R>></import$<ANGLE-R>>
   </imports>
```

output.xml

```
   <imports>
      <import iuts="yes">${COURAGE_COMPOSITES}</import>
   </imports>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `file(GENERATE)` doesn't expand variables at all.

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate) for that command tells nothing about variable's expansion

> Generate an output file for each build configuration supported by the current CMake Generator. Evaluate generator expressions from the input content to produce the output content.

If you want to expand variables, you could firstly expands them with command [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) into **intermediate file**, and then expand generator expressions in that file using `file(GENERATE)`:

```
# output.xml.in -> output.xml.im
configure_file(${INPUT_PATH}/output.xml.in ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml.im)
# output.xml.im -> output.xml
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml INPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml.im)
```

Alternatively, if your input file is small, you could embed it into the `CMakeLists.txt` as a **string**, and use `CONTENT` parameter for `file(GENERATE)`:

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml CONTENT
"Variable ${var} and generator expression $<CONFIG>"
)
```

In that case the variable substitution will be performed by CMake itself before it passes the string to the command.

If the input file is not so small for being embedded as a single line, you could use bracket form for embed it into the `CMakeLists.txt`. However, in the bracket form CMake doesn't expand variables automatically, so additional `string(CONFIGURE)` will be needed.

```
# Firstly, expand variables
string(CONFIGURE 
[=[
<imports>
    $<$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:"${COURAGE_COMPOSITES}","">>:<import iuts="yes"$<ANGLE-R>$<JOIN:${COURAGE_COMPOSITES},</import$<ANGLE-R><import iuts="yes"$<ANGLE-R>></import$<ANGLE-R>>
</imports>
]=]
output_intermediate
)

# Then expand generator expressions
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}/output.xml CONTENT "${output_intermediate}"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but really, CMake? I am sure there is a historical reason here, but it's not very intuitive that I can use generator expressions but not variables in file(GENERATE) and AFAIK variables but not generator expression in configure_file.

Comment: Probably, the reason is simple: variables can (and should) be expanded **immediately**, but generator expressions can be expanded only at the **end of configuration process**. `configure_file` creates the file immediately, so it cannot expand generator expressions. In opposite, `file(GENERATE)` creates the file at the end of the configuration process. Because variables could be lost at this stage (they are context-dependent), so they cannot be expanded. Variables and generator expressions seems to be citizen who never meet together:)

Comment: This text only solution evaluates the generator expressions, but does not actually evaluate variables.

Comment: @Krupip: Thanks, I missed that specifics of a *bracket argument*. Now the answer is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this question recently. Since cmake 3.18, there is `file(CONFIGURE ...)` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#configure) which expands variables in the input text.

However, it only takes direct input via `CONTENT`, not via other files like `GENERATE` can. I can't see why they left `INPUT` out for `CONFIGURE`, but it's an alternative to the two-step process described in the current answer.

Comment: I think that is probably because it behaves exactly as configure_file, only for a given input instead of a file. It shares the same limitation of not expanding generator expressions. So in this case, it seems like one would still need a two-step process (one for expanding variables, one for generator expressions).